# How do I find my GitHub repository git:// protocol?

Tags: protocols, external-url

Verbatim.
How do I turn this https protocol Git Repo external Link

```
<a href="https://github.com/jehovahsays/1.git">https protocol</a><br>
```

Into something like this git protocol Git Repo external Link

```
<a href="git://github.com/jehovahsays/1.git">git protocol</a><br>
```

Comment: i guess you simply replace https: with git:

Comment: To me, it looks like they only support SSH or HTTPS so... 1. determine if GitHub supports git:// protocol 2. figure out what the url looks like (different protocols may have different paths)